# Don't show part of pull downs content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some dropdowns in a form that are generated by a backoffice. At the end of each choice in the dropdown something is added between (brackets). How can I not show these brackets and their variable content? Leaving only the content before the brackets.

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo (30.000)</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab (40.000)</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel (15.000)</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi (45.000)</option>
</select>


<select>
  <option value="dog">Dog (300)</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat (50)</option>
  <option value="fish">Fish (5)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you have the markup available?  It looks like you're looking for a javascript based answer.  Do you have some javascript code of what you've tried so far?

Comment: Thanks, @Joseph Marikle! I've added some code to my question. I have no javascript so far, as I would not know where to begin. Still haven't found anything. I need some code that will remove the brackets with content from the choices.

Comment: how is the list generated - hook into it and remove what u want there = most cleanest + performant solution. ;) with js u could get "flickering" which is ugly... so are you sure you want to do it via js?

Comment: Thanks, @MarcelD. Don't know exactly how the dropdowns are generated, just that I fill in some content in a backoffice form and that they then appear in the webpage form. In the backoffice I add if extra cost or discount applies to the each given dropdown choice, and this then appears in the brackets in the pull down. Erdogan's answer work, with a but.. Could you have a look please?

Comment: what kinda "backoffice" are u using?

Comment: Find the answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935503/stop-dropdown-from-redirecting-to-homepage/43937809#43937809](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935503/stop-dropdown-from-redirecting-to-homepage/43937809#43937809)

Answer (score 2):

Try this;

```js
var carList=[{name:"Audi (45.000)" },{name:"Saab (40.000)"},{name:"Opel (15.000)"},{name:"Audi (45.000)"}];

var $cars=$("#cars");
$cars.empty();
carList.forEach(function(index){
  $cars.append(new Option(index.name.split("(")[0].trim()))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cars">
</select>
```

For all select elements

```js
$("select").each(function(){
  var $wrapper=$(this);
  var $options=$wrapper.find("option");
  $wrapper.empty();
  $options.each(function(index){
      $wrapper.append(new Option($(this).text().split("(")[0].trim()))
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option>Fiat (32.00)</option>
<option>Audi (12.00)</option>
</select>

<select>
<option>Bmw (32.00)</option>
<option>Tofas (22.00)</option>
</select>

<select>
<option>Dog (1.00)</option>
<option>Fish (0.00)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Erdogan Oksuz! This does what I want it to do!! But one thing, the dropdowns all have different content and I would like code that removes the brackets with content from all dropdowns. Have added an extra dropdown to my question.

Comment: @Eddy I update answer for all select elements.I hope this helpful

Comment: oops, I found a problem, @Erdogan Oksuz. Can you help please? Some of my pulldowns reload the current webpage, e.g. a pulldown for changing the currency of prices. When I add your code "For all select elements" the current page does not reload, but it skips to the homepage instead.

Comment: @Eddy You must provide a framework or platform for we find the problem ? e.g. `ASP.NET MVC`

Comment: thank you, @ Erdogan. Here is the webpage where the problem occurs: http://www.photographycoursetour.com/japan-photo-tour-photography-course-beginners-or.html  On this page there is a form (where you see "secure your spot") the top dropdown shows dates and prices. This drop down choice should normally regenerate the same webpage, but now goes to the homepage. The dropdowns under this dropdown work fine as they do not regenerate the webpage.

Comment: Also the dropdown for the currency (above and outside of the form, just under the price) also regenerates the webpage and shows the same problem (going to the homepage, instead of staying on the same page). When I take your code out these work fine again. Can you see what is going on? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @Eddy If you want to remove prices **secure your spot > dates and prices** use this;`$wrapper.append(new Option($(this).text().split("$")[0].trim().replace(/.$/,"")))`

Comment: Thanks Erdogan, but your code is already removing what I want. The only problem is, when using your code , that with dropdowns containing choices that will trigger the page to refresh the browser no longer stays on the same page, but goes to the homepage instead. It should stay on the same page.

Comment: @Eddy Your `select` tag have a `onchange` event.Like this; `<select name="variant" id="product_configure_variants" onchange="document.getElementById('product_configure_form').action = 'http://www.photographycoursetour.com/product/variants/25835070/'; document.getElementById('product_configure_form').submit();">` For this reason redirect another page.

Comment: But when I take your code out, without changing anything else, the page does NOT redirect to the homepage. How can this be fixed?

Comment: But when I take your code out, without changing anything else, the page does NOT redirect to the homepage. How can this be fixed? So that the page does not redirect to the homepage, even with I use your code as above under "For all select elements".

Comment: This is your code that I am using: $("select").each(function(){
  var $wrapper=$(this);
  var $options=$wrapper.find("option");
  $wrapper.empty();
  $options.each(function(index){
      $wrapper.append(new Option($(this).text().split("(")[0].trim()))
  })
})

Comment: Find the answer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935503/stop-dropdown-from-redirecting-to-homepage/43937809#43937809](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935503/stop-dropdown-from-redirecting-to-homepage/43937809#43937809)