# Stop dropdown from redirecting to homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery

sI am using the following code to remove text starting from the "+" character from dropdown menu choices:

```
 $("select").each(function(){
  var $wrapper=$(this);
  var $options=$wrapper.find("option");
  $(this).empty();
  $options.each(function(index){
      $wrapper.append(new Option($(this).text().split("+")[0]))
  })
})
```

So if a menu original choices would be:

Audi

BMW

Mercedes + Trailer

The dropdown only shows:

Audi

BMW

Mercedes

THE PROBLEM:

I also have dropdowns that need to refresh the page when a choice is made. When not using the above code this works fine, but when adding the code above the webpage redirects to the homepage instead. How I can ensure that when the user makes a dropdown choice the user stays on the same page?

Comment: Please provide HTML code.

Comment: you are not adding value to your new option just text

Comment: Thanks @R.K.Saini. Is this causing the browser to redirect to another page? What should the code look like?

Comment: The problem, @R.K.Saini, is not that the text is not being removed successfully. The problem is that dropdowns that refresh the current page (e.g. dropdown for language choice) redirects to the homepage instead of to the current page. When I remove the code for removing the text, the dropdown does not redirect to the homepage anymore.

Comment: ok, have tried code  i added in my answer ?

Comment: you need to show the HTML of these selects and how the redirect is being triggered. Is it that you want to exclude the selects that perform redirects from your "each" loop, or you want to preserve the "correct" redirect behaviour, or what?

Comment: Thanks @ADyson, I want to preserve the "correct" redirect behavior.

Comment: ok well as I said you need to show us how it is working currently. Please share the HTML for the selects and any script which is causing the redirection. My guess is that perhaps the redirect destination depends on the option selected, and your new "each" loop is destroying the relevant options. But until you show the code, that's just a guess.

Comment: Thanks again @ ADyson. Reproducing the html and script is difficult for me.  The dropdowns are generated by a webshop backoffice. Please see here: http://www.photographycoursetour.com/japan-photo-tour-photography-course-beginners-or.html  The dark blue currency button (on the right side of the page, under the price) should redirect to the same page but, after adding the code for removing the text from dropdowns, no longer does, but instead now goes to the homepage.

Comment: @Eddy I see it got solved now, but for future reference, you can easily just use the "View Source" or "inspect element" options in your browser to see the HTML that's generated by server-side code such as yours. Then you can paste that into questions such as these.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the tip, @ADyson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the jquery spirit "write less, do more" you could also do the text replacement operation like this:

```js
$("select.cars option").each(function(){
 with ($(this)) {
  text(text().split("+")[0].trim());
  val(val().split("+")[0].trim());
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="cars">
<option value="Audi">Audi</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
<option value="Mercedes + Trailer">Mercedes + Trailer</option>

</select>
```

To limit the effect of the script on the selects you want to change and protect all the others I also added the class "cars" into the picture. Maybe something along those lines can be helpful for your project?

But this will *not* touch your current problem, that you leave the current page as soon as a select option has been selected. I suspect there must be another piece of (as yet unpublished) script that is responsible for that behaviour.

Comment: THANK YOU, @cars10. You are not kidding "write less - do more". Writing less eliminates the problem altogether :) and only performs the change of removing the text that I wanted removed. In other words: IT WORKS!! Thank you!!!

Comment: I also just added the `val()` part to my answer. Forgot to put it in in the first version.

Comment: It did not seem to need the val()

Comment: In fact adding the val() presents a problem that the text I want removed is not removed.

Comment: Well, in that case: leave it out! ;-)

Comment: yep, I have! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add value to newly created option.

Try this:

```js
$("select").each(function(){
  var $wrapper=$(this);
  var $options=$wrapper.find("option");
  $(this).empty();
  $options.each(function(index){
      var text = $(this).text().split("+")[0].trim();
      var newOption = new Option(text);
      // get value from previous option 
      newOption.value= $(this).val();
      $wrapper.append(newOption)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option value="Audi">Audi</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
<option value="Mercedes + Trailer">Mercedes + Trailer</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @R.K.Saini, but unfortunately your code makes no difference to the problem of redirecting to the homepage. Please see here: http://www.photographycoursetour.com/japan-photo-tour-photography-course-beginners-or.html  , the currency button (under the price) should not redirect to the homepage, but stay on the same page. When I remove the code for removing text the browser does stay on the same page.

Comment: You are using $("select") selector to add new option. So it will be called on all dropdown available in page. Do you want to change option for all dropdowns ? Please explain your requirement a little bit more.

Comment: Do you want to redirect functionality on your currency dropdown ?

Comment: @ R.K.Saini, I have various dropdowns. Some of these will refresh the page, some will not refresh the page. The ones that refresh the page are redirecting incorrectly to the homepage now. They need to stay on the same page. I am using $("select") because dropdowns on the page have a varying class name or id name.

Comment: Currency selection needs to stay on the same page. As does the selection of a Event Date in the order form (under "secure your spot") .

Comment: Ok, I update my answer check now. Now it will not use option text as value it will use existing option value to populate value for new option

Comment: @ R.K.Saini, you're close!!! On the currency dropdown it works, thanks! On the EVENT DATE dropdown (under "secure your spot") it also now stays on the same page  :) but the choice made there is not being shown in the dropdown :( Other dropdowns under EVENT DATE work fine, they never refresh the page anyway.

Comment: I do see that the EVENT DATE uses an extra bit of code:  var e = $("#product_configure_variants");
var error = $("#error")
var valid=false;
e.change(function() {
  if (e[0].selectedIndex === 0) {
    error.text("help");
  }
  else{
    valid=true;
    error.text("");
  }
}) Do I need to change something in this script. Or rather, counteract something in this script with your script. Because I don't know if this script  js.file is loaded elsewhere in the webshop too.

Comment: You are submitting a form on change of event date (document.getElementById('product_configure_form').action = 'http://www.photographycoursetour.com/product/variants/25835070/'; document.getElementById('product_configure_form').submit();. So you need to get value back form posted data on server and repopulate it to form.

Answer (score 0):

So this works!

```js
$("select option").each(function(){
 with ($(this)) text(text().split("+")[0].trim());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="cars">
<option value="Audi">Audi</option>
<option value="BMW">BMW</option>
<option value="Mercedes + Trailer">Mercedes + Trailer</option>

</select>
```